# How to prepare specific view? -RN

Tags: javascript, react-native, responsive-design

I'm new to app development. I want to prepare a different View like the picture below. I tried but I couldn't. When I did the View was not responsive. Is there an easier and more responsive way for me to do this?

I want to do:

[image]

My codes:

```js
import React from "react"
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native"

const units = {
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
}

export default function Main( ) {

    return (
        <>
            <View
                style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.leftBlock} />
                <View style={styles.middleBlock} />
                <View style={styles.rightBlock} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.circle}/>
        </>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    leftBlock:{
            height: 50, 
            width: units.width / 3, 
            backgroundColor: "black",
            borderTopRightRadius: 10
    },
    middleBlock:{
        height: 50, 
        width: units.width / 3, 
        backgroundColor: "black",
    },
    rightBlock:{
        height: 50, 
        width: units.width / 3, 
        backgroundColor: "black",
        borderTopLeftRadius: 10
    },
    circle:{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: units.width / 2.5,
        height: units.width / 2.5,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        bottom: 10,
        left: units.width / 3.35,
        borderBottomRightRadius: 999,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: 999,
    }
})
```

My Codes Results:

[image]